# Are these sentences natural? If not, is the grammar at least correct?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-japanese

Are these sentences natural? If not, is the grammar at least correct?

> For 2 years, my goal was to pass the JLPT N3. Since passing in December, I've rarely studied Japanese at all. I've already forgotten lots of words, grammar and kanji

> 2年間JLPT N3に合格するのは私の目標だった。でも１２月に合格して以来めったに日本語を勉強してなかった。もうたくさんの言葉と文法と漢字を忘れてしまった。

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not handle proofreading questions that don't have a clear focus. Please read [this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010).

Answer (score 1):

いいと思います。意味は十分伝わります。

しかし強いてこの文章を改善するなら、

> 2年間JLPT N3に合格するのは私の目標だった

のところを

> 2年間JLPT N3に合格するの**が**私の目標だった

のように変更したら良いかと思われます。

言い換えると、「2年間の間、”JLPT N3に合格する”という事が目標だった」と言うことなので。

---

他にも、（これは完全に私の感覚に過ぎませんが）「だった」と「でも」を組み合わせるより

> 〜私の目標だった。でも１２月に合格して〜

を

> 〜私の目標でした。しかし１２月に合格して〜

のようにすればよりネイティブからしたらよりキレイな日本語に聞こえると思います。

しかし「でした」や「しかし」は一般的に言う**敬語**の部類に入るので、話し言葉で話したい場合は

> 〜私の目標だった。**だけど**１２月に合格して〜

の様な使い方をすれば良いと思います。